# How to show two lists of different collections in one page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I want to show a list of `TodoCollection` followed by a list of `FinishedCollection`. I can put them in two lists then inside a `StackPanel`. but a stackpanel doesn't support virtualization and isn't optimized for big data.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TodoCollection}"
            ItemClick="TodoCollection_ItemClick"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TodoTemplate}"/>
    <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FinishedCollection}"
            ItemClick="FinishedCollection_ItemClick"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FinishedTemplate}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**How to show two lists one after another in a page?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep virtualization of `ListView` then you can use `Grid`, or any other `Panel` that does not give its children infinite space to grow

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView 
        Grid.Row="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TodoCollection}"
        ItemClick="TodoCollection_ItemClick"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TodoTemplate}"/>
    <ListView 
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding FinishedCollection}"
        ItemClick="FinishedCollection_ItemClick"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FinishedTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks, this doesn't help. it'll divide the page to two equal sections, but I want second list start after the first one

Comment: I thought both lists are long and need virtualization. Did you try setting first row height to `Height="Auto"`?

Comment: yes they are long. only first list will scroll and the second list won't come up to the screen after setting Height to Auto.

Comment: How did it work with `StackPanel` then? Was the second list visible? You must limit space given to second `ListView` if you want to keep virtualization